# Getting redirected to wy-in-f147.1e100.net

Tags: dns, gmail

I am a MAC OS user, more precisely I'm running snow leopard.

Today when I tried to access google I was redirected each time I've entered "google.com" (or any other google service, e.g. gmail), whether using Chrome or Safari.  In gmail case I was prompted to accept an certificate belonging to akamai.net.

After this I opened a terminal and did a traceroute to google.

The traceroute showed me that google.com was wy-in-f147.1e100.net. Knowing this, I cleaned my DNS cache, solving the redirecting problem.

I would like to know if this problem is known and what may have caused it.

Comment: 1e100 = 1 googol. 1e100.net is owned by Google and is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick

```
whois 1e100.net
```

and it gave me

```
Domain Name: 1e100.net

    Registrar Name: Markmonitor.com
    Registrar Whois: whois.markmonitor.com
    Registrar Homepage: http://www.markmonitor.com

Administrative Contact:
    DNS Admin
    Google Inc.
    1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
     Mountain View CA 94043
    US
    dns-admin@google.com +1.6502530000 Fax: +1.6506188571
```

So it checks out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't remember to do that.